# DataGridView: Choose columns and set their peoperties when populating via SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

I populate a DataGridView using a query in code, I select more columns than I need however. The columns I don't want to show are needed for an insert query, so I need to display A,C,E, and have the user enter info into column E, but then an insert statement will need all A,B,C,D, and E from the grid. Is there a way to specify which returned columns I want to display and set their properties, such as column width and if it an be edited.

My Current code is:

```
dg_Data1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

string sql = "select a,b,c,d from X inner join Y where Z";

   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
   using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
   {
        connection.Open();
        var myTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(myTable);
        dg_Data1.DataSource = myTable;
   }
```

The number of columns returned total and that I need to display will always be the same, and in same order.

Comment: You could create a DataView or just set some columns to invisible

Comment: How would I specify which columns to make invisible?

Comment: `myDGV.Columns[n].Visible = false;`  In come cases it might be worth have something like a Layouts collection to set each DGV up however you need and/or to restore user changes like column width

Comment: @Plutonix ah and I can use that same myDGV.Columns[n]. to specify all other properties such a width :D You've answered all my question.